# Problem with htaccess rewrite URL from https://www.test.com/demo to https://www.test.com/test/demo

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to redirect (not visible in browser url) from https://www.test.com/demo to https://www.test.com/test/demo

If I use this rules it's ok but visible in browser url :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^www.test.com$"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/test"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "https://www.test.com/test/$1" [L]
```

If i do the same with it's KO, with an internal apache error "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects" :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^www.test.com$"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "!^/test"
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "/test/$1" [L]
```

All rewrite rules :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Specifique
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /test/$1 [END]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The second attempt makes sense, but your condition will never match.
Take a look at this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /test/$1 [END]
```

Or even simpler:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^ /test%{REQUEST_URI} [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a distributed configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http servAnd a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Those distributed configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare). er and enabled in the http host. In case you use a distributed configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but result is the same, my conditions was match. If I use your proposal :

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /test/$1 [END]`

I have an error "Document not found", but if I change to ths it's work but the url in the browser is changed and i don't want that.

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.test.com/test/$1 [END]`

Comment: You need to understand the difference between "rewrite" and "redirect". Of course a redirection will get performed if you use a full URL as the target of a rule. And of course that changes the URL visible in the browser, since the browser is explicitly instructed to make a new request.

Comment: From your description one might get the impression that there are other, additional rewriting rules present which you did not show here. Maybe located somewhere else in your setup which we do not know.

Comment: Also make sure that you are really not just looking at lient side cached results. _Always_ test using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Comment: Please find bellow the full rules present, and yes I always use a anonymous browser window ;-)

Comment: Hard to say, you'd have to enable rewrite logging to understand in detail what is going on. It _mighty be_ that thee issue is that you are first rewriting to the test folder, but that in there the rewriting to the front controller is not performed, since you terminated the rewriting process after the first step by the `END` flag. But that is something you need to examine, I know to little details of all your setup and what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    
    # Specifique
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ 
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /test/$1 [END]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This is not an answer. Please post additional information by editing your question. There is an "edit" link below it. _Use it_ ...

Comment: Great, thanks. and then it makes sense to delete this "answer"...